# enum static map will not work for localization if user change device language

Tags: android, enums, static

As per my requirement, application have to reflect string changes as per locale change on device. But here mostly used static Map to hold enums which will reinitialize after locale change.

Below is sample code :

```
public enum Color{

    Green(R.string.green),
    Warning(R.string.red),
    ENSLow(R.string.blue),
    Zero(R.string.orange),

 private static Map<String, Color> colorMap = new HashMap<String, Color>();
  private final int mResId;
}

 static {
        for Color color : values()) {
            colorMap .put(appContext.getResources().getString(state.mResId), color);
        }
    }

    Color(int resId) {
        mResId = resId;
    }
```

Please suggest me how can i avoid use of static map for color ?

Comment: Make the map with the resource id: ` Map<Integer, Color>` instead of the resolved `String` and add a method to your enum to get it when needed.

Comment: Why do you need this? Current activity of your app is rebuilt on locale change, therefore the strings are reinitialized.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create your own constants in this way. Android do it already for you.

Just use always `appContext.getResources().getString(R.string.green)`

From [Supporting Different Languages](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html):

> At runtime, the Android system uses the appropriate set of string resources based on the locale currently set for the user's device.

So your strings are already cached.

Check this: [Resources.java#Resources.getText(int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-0/android/content/res/Resources.java#Resources.getText%28int%29)